# Unable to create role with cassandra account

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to create roles in Cassandra while logged in as the default cassandra user and this error pops up

```
cassandra@cqlsh> create role admin with password = 'admin'
    ... and superuser = true
    ... and login = true;
Unauthorized: Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Only superusers can
create a role with superuser status"
```

I should also note that I've changed `authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator` to `authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator` and `authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer` to `authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer` in the cassandra.yaml file and have restarted the Cassandra service after making those changes but the error still pops up.

Comment: What C* version are you using?

Comment: @Horia I'm on 3.11.4

Comment: Had same problem and did not find a solution yet